# How can I translate this phrase? " To break with the past"

Tags: translation

> In 1791 the French nation, in the midst of a revolution, wished to break with the past, especially with those aspects of it which they considered illogical and useless.

This phrase is the topic of my text and also use in the text. Please help me. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure it's "a break *with* the past" or is it "a break *from* the past"?

Comment: No it's "to break with the past"

Comment: “Break with the past” is a fixed phrase with many definitions available via search, including [suggested translations](http://www.wordreference.com/enfr/break%20with%20the%20past). Which did you find? Where exactly are you confused?

Comment: I have a problem with translation. I don't know what does break mean exactly here?!

Comment: I think the confusion comes from the fact that it means the same thing it always does: an interruption of continuity.

Comment: It might be worth pointing out that, if _break_ has [three dozen meanings or so](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/break), and _past_ has [a number of ways it can be used](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/past), it might be challenging for a learner to translate "break with the past." While I agree that the question could have shown a bit more research, I also understand how this might be a tough nut to crack. Let's not forget ELL was created so that people could ask questions like this one: obvious to the native, but hard for the learner to figure out.

Comment: @J.R. My point is that a search for “break with the past” has many useful results. It's hard to know what else is needed without more information.

Comment: @TylerJamesYoung - I understand that, but I can also see how someone could get lost very quickly if they tried to interpret this word by word, instead of as a single phrase. Note that this particular user has been at ELL for a whopping total of nine days. Some of these tricks can take awhile to learn.

Comment: @J.R. I've taken that same belief and done three things: 1. I voted to close the question because it does not fit ELL in its current form, 2. I made a request for more detail, so that the question might be edited to fit, 3. I curated the relevant search results below in the hopes of learning more about the specific nature of OP's confusion. Incidentally, I'm not sure where you're getting "nine days". I'm seeing 3 months here and 5 months on ELU, with a record of similarly received questions wherein would-be respondents ask for basic research and/or more detail to be included.

Comment: @Tyler - You're right; it's three months. My bad on that one. And I don't want to argue with you, because I find myself agreeing with 99% of the comments you make, and I agree here that the question could stand some improvement.

Comment: @J.R. Do you disagree that we agree? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps this would be easier to explain if we talked about romantic breakups, rather than French history.

Let's say Joe and Jane dated for about 2 or 3 years, and have recently ended their relationship. While dating, one of their favorite places was McArthur Park, where they would frequently take long walks in the evening.

About two weeks after the break up, one of Joe's friends asks if he wants to go throw a frisbee down at McArthur Park. Joe replies:

> Throwing a frisbee sounds fun, but can we do it somewhere else? Maybe out by the creek?
>   Why not McArthur Park? It's nice down there.
>   I know it is. But Jane and I used to go down there all the time, and I'm trying to *break with the past*.

Essentially, Joe is saying that he's trying to forget about his life with Jane, and going to the park would make that hard to do.

In addition to *break with the past,* other ways we can express this concept include:

> *get a new* (or *fresh*) *start*
>   *put the past behind me*

One opposite of *breaking with the past* would be *cherishing the memories*.

Parts of our past are parts of our personal history (or, in the case of France, part of its national history). When someone tries to *break from the past*, they try to disassociate themselves with parts of their prior history. For example:

- A criminal who is released from prison may want to break from his past by living an upright life.
- A person who made a lot of mistakes might want to break from their past by moving somewhere else.
- At the end of a civil war, and country might want to break from its past by building coalitions and reconstructing itself.

Answer (score 1):

### [Definition of break from ODO](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/break)

[image]

---

### [Suggested French translation from wordreference.com](http://www.wordreference.com/enfr/break%20with%20the%20past)

- *rompre avec la tradition*
- *rompre avec la coutume*

Comment: Actually I don't understand what you said. Can you explain more?

Comment: @IceGirl I have provided the sense of “break” that is used in the phrase “break with the past” and examples of it being used in this way. The second half of the answer includes a couple of ways the phrase could be translated into French (my guess at the language you wanted, based on the nation mentioned in the example itself). The link allows you to switch languages if you are looking for different translations. I don't know how else to answer your question given the information provided. Perhaps you can write more about what you think it means or what you are ultimately trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

The French nation wished ***"to break with the past"*** means that the French nation wished "to start doing things in a completely new way".

> **[break with](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/break-with)**
>   <sup>phrasal verb [transitive]</sup>
>   2 **break with something** if someone breaks with the past or with tradition, they start doing things in a completely new way
>   *Some women broke with tradition by going to study abroad.*

Answer (score 0):

To break with the past  means **to end a connection with it**. So in your text it means that the French nation wished to end any connection with the past.